# What does this sentence mean?

Tags: translation

I do not know if this website accept translation requests but here is the sentence, it is an hebrew religious concept, this is all I know about this sentence. A friend told it to me and I want to know what it means. It was in the middle of a religious discussion.

"Hutshuva  Hutfila, Huzdaka mavirim (mevatlim?) et roa agzera"

Comment: Please [edit] in information about where you encountered this sentence and why you're interested in learning what it means.

Comment: http://www.mesora.org/RewardPunishmentii.htm

Comment: thanks ! what about "mevatlim" ?

Answer (score 8):

To add a little bit:

This sentence (in Hebrew: ותשובה ותפלה וצדקה מעבירין את רוע הגזרה, *uteshuva utefila utzedaqa ma'avirin et roa' hagezeira*) is from the well-known *piyyut* (liturgical poem) [Unetaneh Tokef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unetanneh_Tokef), which is recited during the High Holidays. It is attributed (probably apocryphally) to a certain 11th-century rabbi, Amnon of Mainz but is probably a few centuries older than that.

The sentence from *Unetaneh Tokef*, which has been translated in the other answers, draws on the language of [*Genesis Rabba* (an early midrashic compilation) 44:15](http://HebrewBooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=104), where it says:

> ר' יודן בשם ר' אלעזר אמר: שלושה דברים מבטלין גזירות רעות, ואלו הם:
> תפלה וצדקה ותשובה.
>
> Rabbi Yudan said in the name of R. El'azar: three things annul [*mevatlin*] evil decrees, and they are: prayer, charity, and repentance.

*Ma'avirin*, the word used in Unetaneh Tokef, is closer in meaning to "averting" or "shifting", which "mevatlin" is like "annulling" or "canceling", but I couldn't give you a good answer as to why the poet chose to use one word over the other. Hope this clarifies this beautiful sentence for you.

Answer (score 1):

“teshuva (repentance) tefila (prayer) and tzedaka (charity) avert the evil decree”

Comment: I do not understand your post. I am asking for the difference between mavirim et mevatlim.

Comment: Are you talking to yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Repentance, Prayer, and Charity (Mavirim =) take away (Mevatlim =) destroys the bad decree.

Comment: thanks, what about "mevatlim" ?

Comment: Destroys? Do you mean annulls? Also its more like "the badness of the decree" not "the bad decrees"